# Fill NA in pandas series with matching value from another pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series, fillna

I have a pandas series like this: [image]

I want to fill NA in matchess with "Lock" value from standard series.

I tried pd.merge and combine_first but it won't reserve the order of matchess. How to fill NA in matchess with the values from standard series while reserving the order of matchess series?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
matches.fillna('Lock')
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**